# Matching images saved in a database

Tags: android, mysql, wamp

I want to match images saved in 2 tables in a mysql database and output the matching images into an android app. I am using wamp as the server. Do i have to use opencv to match the images or is there any other easy way to do this? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't simple join do the job? Smth like `SELECT table1.image FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.image=table2.image`

Comment: Thank you.But actually i need to match a image with series of templates and find which template is matching with the image. Templates are black and white and images color images which are capture by a phone camera.